# running ASP.net application on a different port

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, iis, iis-express

I need to run my asp.net application on port 5000 because this port number is configured in my azure portal. In order to put the Port number 5000, I changed the web tab in the project properties to run at 5000 like this:

[image]

I also clicked on "Create Virtual directory" after putting the new port number.

After this, I changed the applicationhost.config file that exists in my solution folder and changed the bindings like this.I unloaded the project and changed the bindings and then loaded the project again.

```
 <bindings>
                        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:5000:localhost" />
                        <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:5000:localhost" />
   </bindings>
```

The problem is no matter how many times, I change the binding information for https, it always changes back to 44347. How can I keep the port to 5000 for https? I am using Visual studio 2019. .net framework 4.7.2.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IIS Express requires extra config to use a port outside the range 44300-44400, including 5000.

Comment: You are using `asp.net mvc` not a`sp.net core` right?

Comment: yes, I am using asp.net MVC

Comment: You don't need to change the bindings manually it will be set automatically when you would change under `web`  in `project Url` then set `http://localhost:5000/` and `Create Virtual Directory` in my case its working absolutely fine.

Comment: It will show the port # , but if you see the applicationhost.config file, the https bindings will be changed to a different port.

Comment: I found that you have post this question in Microsoft Q&A. I will discuss with you in Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not using the correct profile to run your service through Visual Studio.

If you go into `Properties/launchSettings.json`, you'll see the different profiles that your service can run under. Here's an example screenshot:
[image]

You'll see the two main profiles I have, `IIS Express` and `TrialWebApp.Service`.
From line 6-8, the port for `iisExpress` is defined.

You can select the profile to run your app in the run configuration at the top tool bar:
[image]

You just have to select the one you want, which in your case is likely what corresponds to `TrialWebApp.Service`.

Comment: I don't think this applies to ASP.NET 4.x.